# Unable to add in Mutable list

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using Mutable list so I can pass it to Recycler View. everything is going smoothly when I am adding manually to the mutable list; however, when I use the for loop to add it while fetching the data from Firebase, the Mutable list is acting strangely.
I used debugger and Log to identify what is the issue for many hours but I could not find what is the problem!
While debugging I found the mutable list(listOfKeys) inside the loop is fetching data from Firebase, but for unknown reason when it go out from for loop it doesn't contain any data from for loop, only the data before for loop!!

```
  val listOfKeys: MutableList<OneKeyEvent> = mutableListOf(OneKeyEvent())
  listOfKeys.add(OneKeyEvent("hello", "test")) // it is working
  val user = auth.currentUser
  val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
  val currentUser = user!!.uid
  //Log.d("!current user", currentUser)
  val query = db.collection("Accounts").document(currentUser).collection("Keys").get()
  query.addOnSuccessListener { result ->
     for (document in result) {
        Log.d("!DATA", "${document.id} => ${document.data}") // I can see the data
        listOfKeys.add(
           OneKeyEvent(
              document.data["account"].toString(), document.data["category"].toString()
           )
        )
     }
  }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
     Log.d("!ERROR", "Error getting documents:", exception)
  }
```

OneKeyEvent is just a data class

```
data class OneKeyEvent(var key_account: String = "", var key_category: String = "") {}
```

Any help it would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you tried `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`? This might be caused because you're adding the manual things before you're attaching the adapter whereas onSuccessListener might run after fetching the data (might be after list has been attached to the adapter).

Comment: `when it go out from for loop` what do you mean by that ? your list will populate with data with async way. Just print `list` size immediately after for loop in side `addOnSuccessListener` you will get all the data

Comment: I added manual data before or after the for loop it shows the data in the adapter, but inside the for loop it doesnt!

Comment: @Coder add `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` just below for loop.

Comment: Thank you AbuYousuf, i didn't know it is working async. Thank you Animesh Sahu, I added the notify after the loop inside addOnSuccessListener as Abu Yousuf said, it worked.